# How can I count the number of matching zero elements between two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, data, numpy

I have a function that returns the predicted accuracy of a time-series model. I have two equally-sized numpy arrays, one for the actual direction and one for the predicted direction. I'm classifying whether there is a change in the data's direction from the previous t-1 step.  '1' stands for an increase from t-1, '0' stands for no change in direction, and '-1' stands for a decrease from t-1. I'm trying to compare the elements of both arrays to determine if they both contain the same data to determine accuracy.

I can match indexes and count the number of '1s' and '-1s' that match,  but I cannot count the number of matching zeros. (It's kinda hard summing zeros). :-)  Anyway, I've tried the numpy sum function specifying '0' as the argument for both arrays but it only returns an array of zeros but no count.  I'm not trying to create a confusion matrix...the goal here is to create an accuracy score.  I plan to take all the matching ones, negative ones and zeros and divide that by the total length to get an accuracy score.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `numpy.array([0,-1, 1]) == np.array([0,-1,1])` will return a boolean array, that you can sum over, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare the predictions with the expected results directly, using simple comparisons, in this case just `==`. This returns boolean values - `True` or `False`, which you can sum up because `True == 1` and `False = 0`.

Here is an example for your case using some randomly generated dummy data:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                           

In [2]: y = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], 10)                                                                                         

In [3]: preds = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], 10)                                                                                     

In [4]: y                                                                                                                            
Out[4]: array([ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  0])

In [5]: preds                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: array([ 0, -1,  1,  0,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0])
```

The real part that checks where your predictions are correct is then done using two checks:

1. where are the predictions equal to the ground truth i.e. where were you correct in predicting the direction, **and**
2. where are the predictions equal to the direction you are interested in i.e. downwards (`-1`), no change (`0`) or upwards (`1`)

This can be done as follows:

```
In [6]: (y == preds) & (preds == 0)   #   &   means we needs both checks to be True 
Out[6]:
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True])
```

We can see only the final position is True after both these checks, because that is the only place that the prediction was `True` and the value direction was `0`.

You can then write a loop to check all values and do something with them:

```
In [7]: n = len(preds)    # the number of test samples (= 10 in my dummy example)

In [8]: for direction in [-1, 0, 1]:
            score = sum((y == preds) & (preds == 0)) 
            accuracy = score / n 
            print(f"Direction {direction:>2}: {score}/{n} = {accuracy * 100:.1f}%")
```

Which gives:

```
Direction -1: 1/10 = 10.0%
Direction  0: 1/10 = 10.0%
Direction  1: 1/10 = 10.0%
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @brohjoe  :)  If I answered your question, please consider marking it as resolved.